# Rivlin-Ericksen theorem (Order $n$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**[Ciarlet 1.3-10]** Denoting by $\mathscr{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathscr{O}_n(\mathbb{R})$ the sets of symmetric and orthogonal matrices respectively, of order $n$, show that a function
$$\mathscr{H} : \mathscr{S}_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathscr{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$$
satisfies
$$\mathscr{H}(QBQ^T)\ =\ Q\mathscr{H}(B)Q^T,$$
for every $Q\in\mathscr{O}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and for every $B\in\mathscr{S}_n(\mathbb{R})$, if and only if it is of the form
$$\mathscr{H} : B\in\mathscr{S}_n(\mathbb{R}) \longmapsto\mathscr{H}(B)\ =\ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\beta_k(B)B^k,$$
where the functions $\beta_k : B\in\mathscr{S}_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are symmetric functions of the *principal invariants* of $B$, that is to say, functions of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $B$ (*Rivlin-Ericksen theorem*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the proof, extremely big, in: "Ciarlet, P. G., Mathematical Elasticity. Vol. I: Three-Dimensional Elasticity. Amsterdam etc., North-Holland 1988", pages from 109 at 115.

Comment: You're welcome ;)